# Linksys Ethernet switch holds five computers or not?

Tags: networking, ethernet, troubleshooting

I have a Linksys Ethernet switch conected to the Internet. The switch works fine with two computers.

My problem is when I try to connect another two computers, then nothing works.
The switch has five spots to connect cables, one for the Internet and another four computers.

Why does it work with two computers only?

Comment: What is the exact model of this device?

Comment: The ports could be bad...or the cables, or...

Comment: Are you saying that, when you connect the third and fourth computers, the first two stop working?

Comment: You need to add more details to this question for anyone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the router model, you may only have *3* ethernet ports, not 4. This is because on some switches and routers the last port is typically shared with your uplink port; that is, say you have a 5-port switch; 1-3 would be clients, whereas you can either have an uplink (to say, the Internet) or another client to make 4.

However, this highly depends on the switch and what model it is, so this answer may vary.

The image below illistrates this, although in this case this 5-port switch allows 4 clients.

[image]

Comment: that's exactly the model i have. I'm using the ports 1,2 and 5. When i connect the forth cable on the ports 3 or 4 doesn't work and the ports 1,2 and 5 stops works too.

Comment: Use 1-4 and the uplink port. You can only use *either* port 5 or Uplink, not both. And Uplink should never be used for a client machine.

Comment: Another note: This behavior can be seen with the indicator lights. When configured improperly, all the activity lights stop flashing indicating a problem.